# How to search duplicate users in two files and then print those lines?

Tags: for-loop, awk, grep

I have two files: **FILE1** and **FILE2**

#### FILE1:

```
user1        1.1.1.1
user2        2.2.2.2
user3        3.14.14.3
user4        4.4.4.4
user5        198.222.222.222
```

#### FILE2:

```
user1        99.22.54.214
user66       45.22.88.88
user99       44.55.66.66
user4        8.8.8.8
user39       54.54.54.54
user2        2.2.2.2
```

#### OUTPUT FILE:

```
user1        1.1.1.1
user1        99.22.54.214
user2        2.2.2.2
user4        4.4.4.4
user4        8.8.8.8
```

I tried with a for loop but with particular succes..
Can anyone write me a code for this?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the unix command uniq

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq

Assuming space characters and not tabs in the file
something like this may work

cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq -D -w6 | uniq >file3

Sorry, corrected the above mistake...

Comment: Actually it needs a `-d` as I see.

Comment: This solution is not working..
It just join first and second file to third file!

Comment: yes, I should have tried it first, the above solution works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while read user ip ; do match=`grep -E "$user " file2 2>/dev/null` ; if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo $user $ip ; echo $match ; fi ; done < file1
user1 1.1.1.1
user1 99.22.54.214
user2 2.2.2.2
user2 2.2.2.2
user4 4.4.4.4
user4 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fgrep -h -f <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 FILE1 FILE2 | sort | uniq -d) FILE1 FILE2 | sort -k1
```

That cuts out the first field from both files, then searches for duplicates, then searches both files for the related lines. But you can do this with AWK in several ways too... e.g. somthing like:

```
awk '{if ( users[$1] = "" ) { users[$1]=$2 ; printed[$1]=0} else { if (printed[$1]==0) {print $1 users[$1] ; printed[$1]=1 ; print $0 } else { print $0 } }' | sort
```

When it first sees the user, saves the line, then upon next (times) seeing the same user, checks if the very first occurence was printed already, and if not it prints the first occurence, then the actual. If the first occurence was printed, then prints only the actual line.

HTH

Comment: can add -h to fgrep and a final |sort -k1 to match the expectations; neat anywayz

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}($1 in a){print $0;print a[$1]} ' file2 file1 | uniq
user1        1.1.1.1
user1        99.22.54.214
user2        2.2.2.2
user4        4.4.4.4
user4        8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Nicely done. I noticed that the uniq command does not do anything: you get the correct output even without it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt, which preserves the spaces within a line. First, create a script called showdup.awk:

```
# showdup.awk
$1 != lastkey {
    # Flush out the last set: only print out if the last set contains
    # more than one lines
    if (count > 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            print savedLine[i]
        }
    }

    # Reset the count
    count = 0
}

{
    savedLine[count++] = $0;
    lastkey = $1;
}
```

Next, invoke showdup.awk:

```
cat file1 file2|sort|awk -f showdup.awk
```